# What car stereos work well with iPhone Bluetooth A2DP Streaming Audio

Tags: iphone, accessories, bluetooth

The iPhone 3G supports Bluetooth stereo (A2DP) but lacks any volume control.  As a result, my JVC stereo with the KS-BTA200 Bluetooth adapter clipped stereo audio so horribly that I ended up removing the adapter and foregoing the Bluetooth hands free capabilities.  Now, I just use my AUX jack for music and a separate Bluetooth speaker phone (as long as it doesn't do A2DP).

Has anyone been able to get acceptable (not clipped) Bluetooth Stereo Audio from their iPhone to any car stereo?  What models work well?

Comment: Any others have success?  I'd love to make this a resource for any configuration that works.

Answer (score 2):

I bought my wife a Sony Xplod (sorry, forgot the model number) and that works really well with our phones. I would assume that all Sonys work equally as well (if not better).

Comment: Are your phones iPhones?  I had a HTC Tilt that worked great...  The lack of volume control for iPhone makes it troublesome with some streaming audio devices.  If you could provide the specific model of stereo it would be helpful.

Comment: Yes we both have iPhones. I think the sound quality is pretty good. She's got a 2004 Explorer. The only thing is the guys at Best Buy did a bad job installing, so the radio rattled. I had to secure the dashkit myself to stop the loud rattling sound during calls when she hit a bump or something. The guy in this post (http://gadgets.stackexchange.com/questions/137/looking-for-a-high-quality-bluetooth-headunit) has a similar radio, but hates it though.